# spring 3.0.5 how to define interceptor with configurable URI path

Tags: spring-mvc, path, uri, interceptor

I am using spring 3.0.5 MVC and trying to defined `LoginInterceptor` for specified path `/fx`. I looked up and found the way to use is:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <!-- Changes the locale when a 'locale' request parameter is sent; e.g. /?locale=de -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor" />
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mapping path="/fx"/>
        <bean class="com.fxiapi.auth.LoginInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

I want to use this for any page other than Login page for certain URI. Is their a way to ignore login page URI. Also, using this was I am getting following exception:

> 2011-02-07 11:04:22,756  ERROR http-0.0.0.0-8680-1 Context initialization failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 31 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'mapping'. One of '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc":mapping}' is expected.
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)

Can someone please help? Whats the alternate if I cant use  tag?

Comment: your xml is incorrectly defined. I can't tell more from the provided information.

Comment: it seems that you have malformed xml configuration. Can you post it? Alternatively, have a look at XSD that validates your xml config - it will suggest you how to form it properly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message tells you what's wrong - you need the namespace prefix on the `<mapping>` element also:

```
<mvc:interceptor>
    <mvc:mapping path="/fx"/>
    ...
</mvc:interceptor>
```

Comment: Thanks. This works - I missed the namespace. Also, wanted to know in the mapping is there a way to exclude certain url from given path?

Comment: Does that mean the documentation is incorrect? http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html

Comment: Incorrect doc : yep, I noticed that too. Followed the example in the doc, got the same error...